# Sitecore database cleanup error - timeout?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sitecore, sitecore6

I'm getting an error when running db cleanup (control panel > database > clean up database ) on a large sitecore database, large mainly due to the media library blobs table. The error appears after running for around 4 minutes.

```
Job started: CleanUpDatabases|System.InvalidOperationException: This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.ZombieCheck()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Rollback()
at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderTransaction.Dispose()
at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.CleanupBlobs(CallContext context)
at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.CleanupDatabase(CallContext context)
at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.DataProvider.CleanupDatabase(CallContext context, DataProviderCollection providers)
at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Databases.CleanUp.CleanUpForm.Cleaner.CleanUp()|Job ended: CleanUpDatabases (units processed: )
```

Increasing the `DefaultSQLTimeout` in web.config to a large value doesn't appear to make an difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the DataProviderTimeout setting in the web.config in sitecore/settings, works for me - our Master db is about 50GB. Running v6.4.1 Update-1

Answer (score 0):

For me the accepted solution did not work.
In my case I had a big Master database with (apparently) a lot of orphaned media items.
Some research showed that there is a SQL server script from Sitecore that solves this problem.
Bjarke Istrup Pedersen has created a small console .NET program, that runs this script with a nice, simple interface:

http://mixedsitecore.blogspot.dk/2014/05/fixing-database-with-too-many-orphaned.html

It solved the problem for me.